# How to recognize whether a binding comes from?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I was wondering, suppose I do the following:

```
<Some element Command="{Binding FileButton1}" Content="Load into File1" />
...
<Some element Command="{Binding FileButton2}" Content="Load into File2" />
```

and both button basically just load some file into `File1` and `File2` variables. How can I make my `action` implementation of the relay function, recognize which button is called? Can I do something like:

```
FileAddButton1 = new RelayCommand(action, always_true);

FileAddButton2 = new RelayCommand(action, always_true);
```

and then check in the action method which button is called?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CommandParameter to send arguments from View to Viewmodel. [More information on CommandParameter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Some element Command="{Binding FileButton1}" 
              CommandParameter="MyArgument" Content="Load into File1" />
```

So the delegate corresponding to your command will look like,

```
public void OnCommandExecuted(object argument)
{
   // argument is the parameter passed from view.
}
```

Comment: Can I actually, like get its name or something? This would actually remove the need for an additional parameter. Because I actually do get a sender object in my action method.